# Switch statement problems

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm having a problem with my switch statement, sorry if this is trivial, I'm very new! At the switch statement I'm getting the error :

> Syntax error on tokens, Label expected instead.

At each of the cases I'm getting the error :

> Syntax error on token "case", assert expected

Both `productNumber` and `numberOfProduct` are type int input by the user. `total` and `currentTotal` are type `double`.

```
Switch (productNumber) //problem occurs here, at the switch statement and at each case
{
    case 1:
        currentTotal = numberOfProduct * 2.98;
        total += currentTotal;
        break;

    case 2:
        currentTotal = numberOfProduct * 4.50;
        total += currentTotal;
        break;

    case 3:
        currentTotal = numberOfProduct * 9.98;
        total += currentTotal;
        break;

    case 4://
        currentTotal = numberOfProduct * 4.49;
        total += currentTotal;
        break;

    case 5:
        currentTotal = numberOfProduct * 6.87;
        total += currentTotal;
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("The number entered is not a known product number. Known product numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.");
        --count;
}
```

Comment: What programming language? If it is Java then, `Switch` should be `switch` beginning with a small letter.

Comment: It's Java, and that solved all my problems... haha. Thanks a ton. Can't believe it was that easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a syntax error. `switch` needs to be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Switch->switch? you can have a try